# Access clients ios app crash reports in case of an in-house app

Tags: ios, client, remote-access, crash-reports, xcode-organizer

I have developed an iPad in-house app. I gave it to client to test. He is using it and its crashing some times. Now, i know how to get hold of crash reports on my test ipad device. Go to organizer and find device logs for my test iPad and there i can see my crash reports. But how do i get hold of clients iPad crash reports?More questions coming. If you need more info, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this?, i am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Prasad. I used hockey app. Its a pay service.But I think for the 1st month its free. They have good customer service. You can contact them. In my app delegate file i wrote code that would launch an alert view in case of a crash and send the crash report to hockeyapp. There i get the crash reports. I download them and then go through them.

Answer (score 1):

See [Technical Q&A 1747](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1747/_index.html).

Have the person sync their iOS device with iTunes. The crash reports can be found in the folder shown on that page.

Another option is to integrate [plcrashreporter](https://www.plcrashreporter.org) into your app. You can then implement a feature that would allow your app to email the crash report from within the app.